# How to attach a keyup event to Custom Element shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have searched for some time; but only find Polymer answers;
or answers where EventListeners are put on DOM elements *inside* the shadowRoot.

The effect I am trying to achieve with native Custom Elements:

- Only the focussed element should accept (and display) a **keypress**

It is possible to attach a click event to the shadowRoot, it seems I am doing something wrong for the 'keyup' event.

If I put the `EventListener` on the `window` all elements (of course) update with the same key info.

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
           .innerHTML = this.tabIndex;
    this.addEventListener('keyup',evt=>this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'key:'+evt.key);        
  }
});
```

```css
game-toes{
  display:inline-block;
  height:auto;
  width:100px;
  padding:1em;
  border:10px solid green;
}
game-toes:focus { 
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<game-toes tabindex=1></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=2></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=3></game-toes>
```

Comment: I think you cant register keyup event on element that is not focusable unless you hack it with something like `<div tabindex="0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like you were but you need to add some extra code to make it work:

```js
function on(el, evt, cb) {
  el.addEventListener(evt, cb);
  return () => {
    el.removeEventListener(evt, cb);
  }
}


window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      .innerHTML = this.tabIndex;
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this._offKeyup = on(this, 'keyup', evt => {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = evt.key;
      evt.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from leaving this element
    });
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
    this._offKeyup();
  }
});
```

```css
game-toes{
  display:inline-block;
  height:auto;
  width:100px;
  padding:1em;
  border:10px solid green;
}
game-toes:focus { 
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<game-toes tabindex=1></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=2></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=3></game-toes>
```

1. You may want to use `evt.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from leaving the component.
2. You either need to add your eventListener on the component itself OR, create an element in the shadowRoot with the ability to take focus and then set focus on the inner element when the component gets focus. And then you should be able to add the `keyup` event on that internal element.
3. It is safest to add the eventListener in `connectedCallback` and release them in the `disconnectedCallback` unless you never plan to remove your component.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `tabindex` attribute is set to the custom element `<game-toes>`, and not to its Shadow DOM.

As a consequence, you should instead listen to the `keyup` event on the custom element itself :

```
this.addEventListener('keyup',evt=>this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'key:'+evt.key);
```

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot=this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.tabIndex;
    this.addEventListener('keyup',evt=>this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'key:'+evt.key);        
  }
});
```

```css
game-toes{
  display:inline-block;
  height:auto;
  width:100px;
  padding:1em;
  border:10px solid green;
}
game-toes:focus { 
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<game-toes tabindex=1></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=2></game-toes>
<game-toes tabindex=3></game-toes>
```

Alternately, if you want to listen the `keyup` event at the Shadow DOM level, you should set the `tabindex` attribute in an element inside the Shadow DOM.