# When somebody clicks a I want sound to be played

Tags: javascript

When I click key <kbd>A</kbd>, I want my sound to be played but it doesn't seem to work

```js
var key1 = new Audio();
key1.src = "sounds/316898__jaz-the-man-2__do.wav";

var x = document.getElementById("first");
x.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    event.preventDefault();
    key1.play();
  }
})
```

```css
#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="first" src="https://www.mathpages.com/home/piano2.gif">
```

Comment: What does not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi Sound isn't played

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried attaching the `EventListener` to the `window` instead of the element and it works!

```js
var key1 = new Audio();
key1.src = "https://freesound.org/data/previews/316/316913_5385832-lq.mp3";

var x = window; 
x.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    event.preventDefault();
    key1.play();
  }
})
```

```css
#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="first" src="https://www.mathpages.com/home/piano2.gif">
```

You can also try attaching the listener to `document` or `document.body` and it will also work. If you want to attach it to some other elements you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52330155/3091398) question.

Answer (score 5):

Images are not designed to be interactive controls. They cannot (by default) have the focus. They can't have children either.

This means that it cannot be in focus or be the ancestor of the element that is in focus at the time you press <kbd>A</kbd>.

Attach the event handler to something which can be in focus (or the ancestor of such) such as an `<input>` or the `document`.