# How to add keydown listener to shadow dom

Tags: javascript, html, events, web-component, shadow-dom

I've been trying to implement an event listener for the keydown event for a specific web component. The event listener should be placed within the web component, so it can be used in other projects, too. I implemented an onclick listener which works fine: both methods (for the document and for the shadow dom) are being called. However, this does not work for the keydown event.

I already did some research, however, did not find fitting solutions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330155/how-to-attach-a-keyup-event-to-custom-element-shadowroot). According to [this source](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/shadow-dom-and-events.html), the keydown event should be "useable" as is has the `composed = true` property.

Below is my sample code. This problems seems to appear also for the keyup and keypress event. I feel like I'm missing an essential point. Is there any possibility to handle keydown events within a shadow dom?

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let template = document.getElementById("custom-template");

    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      alert("click from shadow dom");
    });
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation(); // doesn't seem to change anything 
      alert("keydown from shadow dom"); // won't run
    });
  }
}

window.customElements.define("custom-template", CustomElement);

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  alert(`click from document; composed: ${e.composed}`);
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  alert(`keydown from document; composed: ${e.composed}`);
});
```

```html
<custom-template></custom-template>

<template id="custom-template">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <div>This is a div</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### source: [How to make keypress event have the target equal to a "selected" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833568/how-to-make-keypress-event-have-the-target-equal-to-a-selected-element)

Your element is not receiving keyboard events because it is not focused when clicked. All elements are not able to recieve focus when clicked as they don't have **tabindex focus flag** set except for the following elements. *[source:[www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/editing.html#specially-focusable)]*

> - `<a>` elements that have an href attribute
> - `<link>` elements that have an href attribute
> - `<button>` elements
> - `<input>` elements whose type attribute are not in the Hidden state
> - `<select>` elements
> - `<textarea>` elements
> - [Editing hosts](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/editing.html#editing-host)
> - [Browsing context containers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/browsers.html#browsing-context-container)

If an element is not in focus keyboard events are recieved by the `body` element.

> When an element is focused, key events received by the document must
> be targeted **at that element**. There may be no element focused; when no
> element is focused, key events received by the document must be
> targeted **at the body element**. *[source:[www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/editing.html#focus)]*

You can make any HTML element able to receive focus and thereby receive keyboard events by adding a `tabindex` property.

#### Web Component shadowDOM example:

**Best played with in the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/1muf82nj/**

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({ mode:"open" })
             .innerHTML = `<style>
                             *:focus-within { background:green }
                           </style>
                           <button>button</button>
                           <input>
                           <div>DIV without tabindex</div>
                           <div tabindex="0">DIV with tabindex</div>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      const log = (e,t=e.target,n=t.nodeName) => this.shadowRoot.append(
                                                document.createElement("br"),
                            e.type, e.type=="keydown" ?" key:"+e.key:"" ," in ",  
                            n=="BODY" ? "e.target=SCRIPT tag!" : t.innerHTML || n);
      this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("click", log); // can't do this.shadowRoot.onclick = ...
      this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("keydown", log);
      document.onkeydown = log;
    }
  });
</script>
<div><h4>Focus an element, then hit a key</h4></div>
<my-element></my-element>
```